# How to avoid multi-threading issue with DbContext in ABP?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspnet boiler plate with .net core 3.1 project. I've a use case where I need to create separate threads for each service bus topic and then all threads will call a repo to get some data from database.

```
IRepository<Product, long> _productRepository
```

Now I want to ask should I avoid using IRepository because of multi-threading issue with DbContext or will IRepository will manage it?
If not, how can I resolve it? I assume by creating a lifetime scope for DbContext. But does ABP boilerplate provides something to handle this? E.g "IUnitOfWorkManager"

Also if creating a lifetime scope for DbContext is the only option, can someone share a snippet to do that with ABP. Thanks

Update:
I am creating a lifetime scope right at the beginning as well:

```
 var topics = await _queueAdmin.GetAllTopicsAsync();
 var tasks = topics.Select(async topic =>
 {
     using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
     {
         var queue = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IQueue>();

         await queue.ProcessTopicMessagesAsync<T>(topic, subscriptionName, callback, cancellationToken);
     }
 });

 await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Update 2:
I've a topic per tenant in service bus. I've a background service that runs every 15 mins and process all messages from all topics in parallel. I am extracting a chunk of 50 messages from a topic and send a db call to get some info about each message and then send it to a microservice that dumps it in a DB and it keeps on doing it until the topic is clear.
IQueue is registered as scoped

```
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
    Component
        .For<IQueue>()
        .ImplementedBy<ServiceBusQueueService>()
        .LifestyleCustom<MsScopedLifestyleManager>()
);
```

Comment: Don't use multithreading in the first place. It's not needed. Neither is a "repository", a DbContext is a high-level multienetity Unit-of-Work, a DbSet is the single-entity Repository. They don't have CRUD methods because they aren't CRUD classes. `creating a lifetime scope for DbContext` no, it's never an option, precisely because DbContext is a Unit of Work and keeps tracking all the objects attached to it. To discard changes, you dispose the DbContext

Comment: `with ABP.` that framework is using a *lot* of the antipatterns found in various "best practices" shopping lists, just to claim it implements "best practices"

Comment: EF Core already works just fine. When eg a web request is handled, ASP.NET Core creates a new DbContext instance. All data loaded through it or attached to it is tracked for changes. No database connection is opened unless you want to load data.  At the very end of the request you can commit all the changes at once by calling `SaveChanges`. That persists all changes in a single database transaction. To discard the changes, just dispose the DbContet. That's why a Singleton DbContext is such a bad idea. You could end up persisting unwanted changes from another request

Comment: I've added an update to my question. Can you have a look please?

Comment: The question's code is deeply broken by the way. Why is `Parallel.Foreach` used at all? `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work with asynchronous methods. Nothing awaits `Task.Run` which means the generated IQueue`  instances will be disposed immediatelly, before the task had a chance to even start.

Comment: the code doesn't use DbContext in another thread by the way. It has serious threading problems due to the incorrect use of `Parallel.ForEach`. What are you trying to do? There's certainly a better way to do it. For starters, why do you have to queue stuff in parallel? What is `IQueue` in the first place?

Comment: If `IQueue` is a scoped service, you're creating a new queue for every topic. For N items you create N queues with one item each. I doubt that's what you want. If it's a singleton, why create a scope at all?

Comment: Are you trying to process all loaded topics with a multithreaded worker? Use `ActionBlock<T>` instead, with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` greater than 1. That class combines an input buffer with asynchronous processing using 1 or more tasks.

Comment: I've added Update 2 in my question. Sorry i didn't add enough information in my original question because I wanted to be specific. But now as you've raised the issues. Can you help me fixing them?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `DbContext` per thread, or you need some way to synchronize the usage of a single `DbContext`. You should use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` for async tasks.

Comment: For sure I wanted to use Parellel.ForEachAsync but it's not available in .net core 3.1

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `Parallel.ForEach` in the first place here. Perhaps you would be better off getting a list of Tasks and using `Task.WhenAll` ([for example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cpzP5K)). But, a red flag for me is the naming of these objects (queues and topics) which suggests you are using something like Service Bus, which may indicate you need a different set of code entirely

Comment: Indeed, it's a service bus. I've added "Update 2" in my original question mentioning what I want to achieve.

Comment: Not quite - there are more buzzwords (eg microservice, service bus)  but even less reason to use parallelism. Queueing an item is supposed to be fast, so why should this happen in the background? A method called `ProcessTopicMessagesAsync` should appear in the worker service, not the `IQueue` interface. In any case, googling for `ServiceBusQueueService` or `ProcessTopicMessagesAsync` returns no results. I suspect these are your own methods.

Comment: Do look at the [ActionBock<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-8.0) class. I suspect it already does what you try to do. You can post/send all messages to the block with a simple loop and just let it process them, eg `foreach(var topic in topics){ await block.SendAsync(block); }`

Comment: No queueing is happening inside of another rest api call. It's just the processing of all queued messages. E.g mobile devices send data to a rest api which enqueue it in a service bus topic and then later my background service process them

Comment: I think I can change it to Task.WhenAll() as well. The only question remains is the DBContext. Do I need to create to create a separate DbContext for each thread?

Comment: Edited my question again with Task.WhenAll

Comment: If this is Service Bus, then you shouldn't be worrying about parallelism anyway, the library should handle that for you.

Comment: No, I've a separate topic for each tenant and that's why I've to process all topics

Comment: What about to move to [dbcontextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) instead of just dbContext ? dbContextFactort is intended for these scenarios.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using that